# Regular expression to match nth occurrence with a lookaround

Tags: regex, r, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have this text:

```
Concept 1:

108 MB * 0.062012 $/MB________________6.70 $

Concept 2:

108 MB * 0.07982 $/MB ________________8.62 $

Concept 3:

125 MB * 0.002215 $/MB________________0.28 $
```

And I want to get the prices "0.062012" , "0.07982", "0.002215" with a specific regex for each one based on their positions, for example: regex1 gets 0.062012 , regex2 gets 0.07982 and so on.

So far I've only managed to get all values ​​with the same regex using a lookaround: `(\\S+)(?= $/MB)`.

P.D: I'm using this R line: `regmatches(data,regexpr("(\\S+)(?= $/MB)", data, perl=TRUE))`

Comment: Aside:  You need to escape the dollar sign to prevent it from being interpreted as an end-of-subject/end-of-line assertion.

Answer (score 0):

Try matching the preceding "Concept 1:" lines to get the specific value:

regex1 = `(?=Concept 1:\\n\\n\\S+ MB \\* )(\\S+)`

or:

regex1 = `(?=Concept\\s+1:\\n\\n\\S+\\s*\\w+\\s+\\*\\s+)(\\S+)`